# Why is setState not rebuilding my GridView.builder? How do I fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, gridview.builder

I am trying to update a GridView.builder with setState and when the change is triggered, the actual state is updated behind the scene but the GridView.builder does not change until I manually refresh the app.

The setState function triggers and I have tested this. Here is the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'image_display_card.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: ChooseScreen(),
  ));
}


class ChooseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ChooseScreen> createState() => _ChooseScreenState();
}

class _ChooseScreenState extends State<ChooseScreen> {
  DisplayCard? currentSelectedCard;

  // The List of image cards
  List<DisplayCard> baseDisplayList = [];

  // These are dummy images I added
  List<Image> listOfInitialImages = const [
    Image(image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/stickFigureMale.png')),
    Image(image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/stickFigureFemale.png')),
    Image(image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/gown.png')),
    Image(image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/hat1.png')),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    baseDisplayList = [
      for (int i = 0; i < listOfInitialImages.length; i++)
        DisplayCard(
          picture: listOfInitialImages[i],
          onCardSelected: () {
            setCardToSelected(i);
          },
        ),
    ];
  }

  /// unselect the previous selected card and
  /// set currentSelectedCard to the new selected card.
  setCardToSelected(int index) {
    if (currentSelectedCard != null) {
      currentSelectedCard!.selectOrUnselect(false);
    }
    print('triggered');
    // set the new selected card.
    currentSelectedCard = baseDisplayList[index];
    currentSelectedCard!.selectOrUnselect(true);
    print('triggered again');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Choose picture'),
      ),
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemCount: baseDisplayList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return baseDisplayList[index];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is `display_card.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DisplayCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Image picture;
  final onCardSelected;
  bool isSelected;

  // TODO: Implement color change on selected picture
  DisplayCard({
    this.isSelected = false,
    this.onCardSelected,
    this.picture = const Image(
        image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/stickFigureMale.png')),
  });

  selectOrUnselect(bool choice) {
    isSelected = choice;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onCardSelected,
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[300],
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: picture.image,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(isSelected ? 0.4 : 0.0),
                BlendMode.srcOver
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've edited it to contain only the necessary code to replicate the error. Sorry for before.

The state of baseDisplayList is updated but the GridView.builder is not rebuilt.

Ragarding how I know the `GridView.builder` isn't rebuilt, I tried changing the backgroundColor of the scaffold in the `setCardToSelected` function and the background color changed but the GridView didn't change. But when I refresh the app immediately afterwards, the GridView updated.

Please, how can I make the `GridView.builder` update when the `setCardToSelected` is called?

Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you post the code of `SelectedCard ` and `DisplayCard` class?

Comment: How do you know the `GridBuilder` didn't rebuild ?

Comment: Please set the updated item to list again.

Comment: Where are you using `currentSelectedCard`?

Comment: Check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using the provider package but I still got the same problem.

It appears you have to build each individual item inside the `GridView.builder` for it to rebuild if there are any changes.

Here is the solution I found to the problem.

This is `main.dart`:

```dart
import 'image_display_card.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: ChooseScreen(),
  ));
}

class ChooseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ChooseScreen> createState() => _ChooseScreenState();
}

class _ChooseScreenState extends State<ChooseScreen> {
  Image? currentlySelectedImage;

  // The List of image cards
  List<Image> baseImageList = [];
  // The list of image card states
  List<bool> baseStateList = [];

  // These are dummy images I added
  List<Image> listOfInitialImages = const [
    Image(image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/stickFigureMale.png')),
    Image(image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/stickFigureFemale.png')),
    Image(image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/gown.png')),
    Image(image: AssetImage('images/testing_stock/hat1.png')),
  ];

  initialize() {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfInitialImages.length; i++) {
      baseImageList.add(listOfInitialImages[i]);
      baseStateList.add(false);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

  /// Changes the currentlySelectedImage and the color of
  /// the chosen card by setting all values in the baseStatesList
  /// to false, then assigning only the chosen one to true.
  setToSelectedImage(int index) {
    currentlySelectedImage = baseImageList[index];
    setState(() {
      baseStateList.setAll(
          0, [for (int i = 0; i < baseStateList.length; i++) false]);
      baseStateList[index] = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemCount: baseImageList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return DisplayCard(
            picture: baseImageList[index],
            isSelected: baseStateList[index],
            onCardSelected: () {
              setToSelectedImage(index);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `DisplayCard` class remains the same except that the `selectOrUnselect` method is no longer needed.

The state of the gridview's contents actually update with setState if they are defined individually inside the gridview.
This method is also shorter. Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used a list of DataRecord types and then used setState to assign the lstData to the list of DataRecords in my model.  The GridView uses the itembuilder receiving lstData as a parameter to build the GridTiles.

```
class DataRecord {
  String WordValue;
  String State;
  int Index;
  DataRecord(this.WordValue, this.State, this.Index);
}

class _Test_SinglePageState extends State<Test_SinglePage> {
  List<DataRecord> lstData = [];

Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index,
      ConcentrationMonitor model, List<DataRecord> lstData) {
    model.lstData = lstData;
    return MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (StaticVar.index1 != 0 && StaticVar.index2 != 0) {
                _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.reset);
                _stopWatchTimer.onExecute.add(StopWatchExecute.start);
              }
              model.checkForMatch(index);
              setState(() {
                lstData = model.lstData;
              });
            }
            ,
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: GridTile(
                    child: Visibility(
                        visible: model.lstData[index].State == "Show" ||
                                model.lstData[index].State == "TempShow"
                            ? true
                            : false,
                        child: Center(
                            child: Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            model.lstData[index].WordValue,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: model.lstData[index].State == "Show"
                                    ? Colors.purple
                                    : Colors.black),
                          ),
                          Text(model.lstData[index].Index.toString(),
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5)
                          //Text(model.lstData[index].State,
                          //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5)
                        ])))))));
  }

Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 400,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate:
                                const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 120,
                                    childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 20),
                            itemCount: lstData.length,
                            itemBuilder: (ctxt, Index) =>
                                _itemBuilder(ctxt, Index, model, lstData))))
```